# font-size on mobile

Tags: css, html5boilerplate

I am using the HTML5 BoilerPlate.

I want to make the font-size of a certain block small ONLY on mobile devices.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
.searchresult {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .search-result {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .search-result {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1140px) {
    .search-result {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}
```

I thought making it ordinary size under the `@media` would work, but the font is small on my Mac and mobile.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are using `min-width`

You Mac (probably big screen) & mobile **is** `min-width 480` & `768` & `1140`.

To make it for mobile & desktop different, you should do this (*keeping your actual code*):

```
.searchresult {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .search-result {
        font-size: 1em;/* mobile font-size */
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .search-result {
        font-size: 1.4em;/*overrule for big screens*/
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1140px) {
    .search-result {
        font-size: 1.4em;/*another overrule for even bigger screens*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to target **small devices** you can use this syntax.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 .search-result {
    font-size: 1em;
 }
}
```

If you want to know more about media queries, you'd better to check [this](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) out. [Here](http://www.observationsofadesigner.com/css-media-queries-for-mobile-devices/) is the list for the other mobile devices, i think it's useful too.